# How to prevent Windows 10 from installing apps upon user creation although all provisioned apps have been removed?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-apps

When installing a new Windows 10 PC, my very first task is to remove the "app" bloatware; I am doing this before I create any additional users. I first remove all packages which already have been installed by entering the following command at a Powershell prompt:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Remove-AppPackage
```

This works so far. I always use `-AllUsers` although this would be not necessary, because at this stage there is only one user with activated account.

Then I would like to prevent the bloatware from being installed for the new users which I subsequently create (of course, again at a Powershell prompt):

```
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online
```

This does not work, or only works in part. When I create a new user afterwards and log in as that user, I have to notice that at least a few of the apps have been installed for that account, although they were in the list of the provisioned apps and should have been removed by the command shown above.

Hence the question: How can I *really* remove all provisioned apps from Windows 10? If it matters, the question pertains to V1909 and later, and to Pro and Enterprise only.

Please note that there are several tutorials and several answers (among others, at this site) which suggest to use the parameter `-AllUsers` with `Get-AppxProvisionedPackage`. I don't know whether this worked with any version of Windows 10 at all, but it definitely does not work with version 1909 and later. Trying it leads to nothing more than this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -AllUsers
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AllUsers'.
...
```